# Who narrated episode 1 of Durarara!!×2 Ten?

Tags: durarara

A good bit of episode 1 of Durarara!!×2 Ten (i.e. episode 13 of the broader "second season") was narrated by one of the female characters. But this show has a gorillion characters, and I can't place which one of them it was.

The end credits list the following female characters for this episode:

- <s>Sonohara Anri (Hanazawa Kana)</s>
- <s>Celty (Sawashiro Miyuki)</s>
- Karisawa Erika (Takagaki Ayahi)
- Yagiri Namie (Kobayashi Sanae)
- <s>Awakusu Akane (Kuno Misaki)</s>
- Mamiya Manami (Tanoue Marina)
- Kamichika Rio (Tomatsu Haruka)
- "Nurse" (Yamamura Hibiku)
- "Woman" (Satou Kanami)

I've struck through the ones where I'm familiar enough with the voice actor to know it can't be them.

Answer (score 2):

http://durarara.wikia.com/wiki/Durarara!!_x2_Ten_Episode_01

the above wiki link states that it was "Rio Kamichika". The link below is her page. enjoy.

http://durarara.wikia.com/wiki/Rio_Kamichika